# format string with int64 value

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, web-services, format

i have a web service in which training number is assigning as per my database

there is a line

`dates + "1";` this lines add 1 in date

like `27012017` will become `270120171`

then i convert this into `int64`

```
newid = Convert.ToInt64(dates);
```

but now i want to add trainer id in this

so i updated my line with this

```
dates ="00"+trainerid +"-"+ dates + "1";
newid = Convert.ToInt64(dates);
```

the error is coming input string is not in correct format,

i know this is because of the addition of `+"-"+`

but i want to store the data in this format only

and my whole portion look like

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string dates = dt.ToString();
dates = dates.Replace("-", "");
dates = dates.Substring(0, 8);
        SqlCommand cmdbill = new SqlCommand("select top 1 * from listmybill where bill_id like @trid order by bill_id desc", con);
        con.Open();
        cmdbill.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trid", "%" + dates + "%");
        SqlDataReader dr = cmdbill.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            value = dr["bill_id"].ToString();
        }

        con.Close();
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdbill);
        DataTable dat = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dat);
        if (dat.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            newid = Convert.ToInt64(value);
            newid = newid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            dates ="00"+trainerid +"-"+ dates + "1";
            newid = Convert.ToInt64(dates);
        }
        con.Close();
```

what should i do here,

i want to enter the data like `001-270120171`
and if i convert toInt64 into string,

there can be problem when a row found in the table

```
if (dat.Rows.Count > 0) 
{
    newid = Convert.ToInt64(value);
    newid = newid + 1; 
}
```

what i need to do now?

i want to store this into my database

Comment: For the string `"001-270120171"` what do you want the integer to actually be?  Since that string is not itself an integer.

Answer (score 1):

I hardly think you will be doing mathematical calculations on this training number string. I suggest that you convert the `int` in your database into a `varchar` using `alter` statement. Then you you will be able to store the training number in whichever format you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can change new id to string and do the following

```
if (dat.Rows.Count > 0) 
{
    newid = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(value)+1);
}
 else
{
   newid="00"+trainerid +"-"+ dates + "1";

}
```

Comment: newid = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(value) + 1);


cannot implicitly convert string to long

Comment: @MumbaiWadala: It's not clear what you're actually trying to *do* here.  Don't just randomly copy/paste code and repeat back error messages.  Elaborate on the problem.  You're trying to convert a string that is *not* an integer into an integer.  Why?  What do you expect the result to be?  What are you doing with that value?

Comment: change your variable type of newid to string. I guess you are declaring it as integer or double.